# Elastic Beanstalk environment url has random characters added

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I created an EB environment using 'eb create' with a cfg.yml file.  The url for the environment has a random string of characters added in the middle like so:

environ-name.**b4adrt4b2o**.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

Does anyone know where these characters are coming from?

Comment: You must have added it while creating the EB environmnet